# Xamarin Binding Title of Navigation page

Tags: xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.forms

i´ve got an little problem. i got like a searchpage, and if you click on an item from the search, you will get so an other page using the navigationpage. i want the title of this page set to the clicked item. here´s what i got:

```
 private async void PatListe_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item is Patient pat)
        {
            PatNN = pat.NName.ToString();
            PatVN = pat.VName.ToString();
            PatInt = pat.Fallnummer;
        }
        PatVN_NN = PatNN + " " + PatVN;
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new PatientView());
    }
```

so this gives me the "name" I want for the title. with debugging and stopping-points, i noticed that this is working. now there are 2 mistakes i guess, one is on the other site in .cs and on in the .xaml file. here´s the one from my .cs-file:

```
 private string PatNameTitle = SuchErgebnisse.PatVN_NN;
```

while debugging, i recognised that this does not get any value, its null. but: i´ve got the same with the PatInt and this is working...
but even if this is working, there´s an other mistake - in my xaml file:

```
 <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="INESVitaAppTest.Views.PatientenView" BackgroundColor="#235d2a" Title="{Binding PatNameTitle}">
```

this gives me nothing even when i m using a string, like " PatNameTitle = "foo"; "
thanks a lot !

Comment: `private string PatNameTitle` should be `public`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

damn, i got it. There was no initialisation of the PatNameTitle....here is what i added:

```
 Title = PatNameTitle;
```

in an method that get´s called when i open this page.. ant then i deleted the Title="{Binding..}"-stuff, now it s orking :) sorry